# Iterating Java Arrays with Streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

So here's a simple algorithmic problem,

> Given a list of integers, check if there are two numbers in this list that when added together give eight (8).

Here's my solution,

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static List<Integer> arrayOne = List.of(1,3,6,9);
    static List<Integer> arrayTwo = List.of(1,6,2,10);

    static boolean validateArray(int result, List<Integer> array){
        for (int i = 0; i<array.size() - 1; i++){
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j ++){
                int value1 = array.get(i);
                int value2 = array.get(j);
                if(value1 + value2 == result){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(validateArray(8, arrayTwo));
    }
}
```

This works fine. What I'm trying to learn is how to rewrite this code in Java 8. As in what the different options with the loops in Java 8.

Comment: Streams aren't really great for comparison of one element to the rest of the stream. There's edge cases like `#max`, or `#sorted`, but overall the solution doing this with streams will be extremely convoluted compared to your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the implementation (*streams or loops*) performing brute-force iterations over the whole list for each element of the list isn't the best way to solve this problem.

We can index the elements by generating a Map of type `Map<Integer,Boolean>` (credits to *@Holger* for this idea), where Keys would represent unique values in the given list and the corresponding boolean Values would denote whether the occurs more than once. Then we can iterate over the Keys of the Map, checking for each key if the corresponding key, which is equal to `result - key` is present in the Map.

There's one edge case, though, that we need to address:

- if `result` is even and there's a single element in the list, which is equal to `result / 2` checking if `result - key` is present in the map is not sufficient and in this case the Value would be handy to check if associated key has a pair (*to construct the target sum*).

If you want to use Stream API firstly to generate a Map, you can use of Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

Then create a stream over the Keys of the Map and apply [`anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation to obtain the `boolean` result:

```
static boolean validateArray(int result, List<Integer> array) {
    Map<Integer, Boolean> hasPair = array.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),  // Key
            i -> false,           // Value - the element has been encountered for the first time, therefore Value is false
            (left, right) -> true // mergeFunction - resolves value of a duplicated Key a true (it has a pair) 
        ));
    
    return hasPair.keySet().stream()
        .anyMatch(key -> key * 2 == result ?
            hasPair.get(key) : hasPair.containsKey(result - key)
        );
}
```

Comment: You only need to know whether there’s a second occurrence, not the total count. `Map<Integer, Boolean> numHasDupe = array.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> false, (a,b) -> true));

      return numHasDupe.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getKey() * 2 == result? e.getValue(): numHasDupe.containsKey(result - e.getKey()));`

Comment: @Holger Fair point, updated the answer.

Comment: By the way, the simplest solution is `Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>(); for(Integer i: array) { if(seen.contains(result - i)) return true; seen.add(i); } return false;`

Comment: @Holger Agree, iterative approach simpler and potentially chipper since not necessarily all the elements end up in the auxiliary collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a bit different solution using `Set<Integer>` to find an addition complement into the result, then you can easily convert the solution into Stream API.

**Iterative approach**

```java
Set<Integer> set = Set.copyOf(array);
for (Integer integer : array) {
    if (set.contains(result - integer) && (result != 2 * integer)) {
        System.out.printf("Found %s + %s = %s", integer, result - integer, result);
        return true;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Found found no two numbers their addition would result in in %s%n", result);
return false;
```

**Stream API approach (with logging)**

```java
Set<Integer> set = Set.copyOf(array);
return array.stream()
    .filter(integer -> set.contains(result - integer) && (result != 2 * integer))
    .findFirst()
    .map(integer -> {
        System.out.printf("Found %s + %s = %s%n", integer, result - integer, result);
        return true;
    })
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        System.out.printf("Found found no two numbers their addition would result in in %s%n", result);
        return false;
    });
```

And if you don't need to log the results and you care only about the result, the whole stream can be simplified and shortened.

**Stream API approach (result only)**

```java
Set<Integer> set = Set.copyOf(array);
return array.stream()
        .anyMatch(integer -> set.contains(result - integer) && (result != 2 * integer));
```

---

**Remark**:
The algorithm used in all snippets above is simple. You iterate each number in the array and check whether its difference from the `result` would be a number found in the `Set<Integer>` of the array (constant look-up: `O(1)`). To eliminate the currently iterated number (in case the requested `result` would be `2 * integer`), such a check is added. This solution assumes there are no duplicated numbers in the input `array`. In such a case, the `Set<Integer>` shall be used instead and there is no need of a conversion.

Comment: Or just `boolean[] seen = new boolean[result + 1]; for(int value:array) { if(value >= 0 && value <= result) { if(seen[result - value]) return true; seen[value] = true; } } return false;` Experts may use a single `long` if `result` is smaller than 64…

Comment: If there are **two** (or more) elements equal to `result / 2` all the snippets would fail to produce the correct result.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko That's what I have pointed out in a remark.